# Convert number into date

Tags: excel

There is a column in Excel with following data.

```
    15052015  
    19012014 
    13022013
```

I want to get that column data in date type (mm/dd/yyyy) and need to have following results:

```
05/15/2015
01/19/2014
02/13/2013
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a true Excel date, do this:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,3,2),LEFT(A1,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
=(MID(A1,3,2)&"/"&LEFT(A1,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,4))
```

You can try to format your data by doing some manipulation on the cell and adding this formula in your cell.

[image]

Comment: Please provide information about why this solution works and what it does.

Comment: @theDmi:- Did you try to copy this formula and test in your excel to see what it does?

Comment: No. Your answer was flagged as very low quality, I saw it in the review queue. And I agree with whoever flagged it, because a line of code without any explanation is not a good answer. So instead of just downvoting (which I didn't do yet) I just wanted to suggest that you could add some information. But you'll have to decide yourself of course.

Comment: @theDmi:- I am not sure what I can add. Anyways tried to add some details and as to how we can apply this formula. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column of numbers and choose Data ► Data Tools ► Text to Columns. Opt for 🔘 Fixed Width, <kbd>Next</kbd>. Then <kbd>Next</kbd>. Then for the *Column data format* opt for *Date* and choose **DMY**. Click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

In VBA, the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) command can make quick work of this.

```
Sub Convert_DMY()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   '<~~ set this properly!
        With .Columns(1)        '<~~ set this properly!
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), _
                                DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                                FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)  'xlDMYFormat = 4
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The `xlDMYFormat` comes from the [xlColumnDataType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlcolumndatatype.aspx) set.